# Is it possible to auto-implement IEquatable<T> and IComparable<T> in C# 11?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, default-interface-member, c#-11.0

When writing C#, I tend to write a lot of value type objects that implement `IEquatable<T>`, `IComparable<T>`, or both.

For the sake of this proposal, let's assume that I'm writing a fictitious struct called `Int256` with equatable and comparable value semantics; for example:

```cs
public readonly struct Int256 : IEquatable<Int256>, IComparable<Int256>, IComparable
{
    public bool Equals(Int256 other)
    {
        // TODO : is this equal to other?
    }

    public int CompareTo(Int256 other)
    {
        // TODO : how does this compare to other?
    }

    public int CompareTo(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is null) return 1;
        if (obj is not Int256 int256) throw new ArgumentException("Obj must be of type Int256.");
        return CompareTo(int256);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Int256 left, Int256 right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }
    
    public static bool operator !=(Int256 left, Int256 right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
    
    public static bool operator >(Int256 left, Int256 right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is 1;
    }
    
    public static bool operator >=(Int256 left, Int256 right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is 1 or 0;
    }
    
    public static bool operator <(Int256 left, Int256 right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is -1;
    }
    
    public static bool operator <=(Int256 left, Int256 right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is -1 or 0;
    }
}
```

Let's also assume that I were to create some other fictitious structs with the same semantics; for example `UInt256` and `Decimal256`. While trivial, those operators become tedious to implement for every value type object.

Recently, I've been looking at C# 11's new language features, specifically static interface methods, which I believe is largely what makes the new generic math interfaces possible. With that in mind, I could add some additional interfaces to my implementation, specifically `IEqualityOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>` and `IComparisonOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>`; for example:

```cs
public readonly struct Int256 : IEquatable<Int256>, IComparable<Int256>, IComparable, IComparisonOperators<Int256, Int256, bool>
{
  ...
}
```

*For completeness, there is no need to implement `IEqualityOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>` here, as they are extended by `IComparisonOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>` anyway.*

Ultimately, this doesn't really solve the problem. All these interfaces do is ensure that the operators are implemented.

My proposal is whether interfaces could be designed that *auto-implement* **some** of the typical boilerplate code associated with `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`, specifically the operators: `==`, `!=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`; for example:

**IAutoEquatable<T>**

```cs
public interface IAutoEquatable<T> : IEquatable<T>, IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool> where T : IAutoEquatable<T>
{
    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator ==(T? left, T? right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }
    
    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator !=(T? left, T? right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

**IAutoComparable<T>**

```cs
public interface IAutoComparable<T> : IComparable<T>, IComparable, IComparisonOperators<T, T, bool> where T : IAutoComparable<T>
{
    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator ==(T? left, T? right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator !=(T? left, T? right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator >(T left, T right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is 1;
    }

    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator >=(T left, T right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is 1 or 0;
    }

    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator <(T left, T right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is -1;
    }

    // Auto-implemented boilerplate.
    static virtual bool operator <=(T left, T right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right) is -1 or 0;
    }
}
```

The intention here is that the implementor would only require implementation of `bool Equals(T other)` and `int CompareTo(T other)` respectively, but, given that the operators are implemented on the interface, they get the operators for free!

Given my `Int256` example, it might look something like this:

```cs
public readonly struct Int256 : IEquatable<Int256>, IComparable<Int256>, IComparable
{
    public bool Equals(Int256 other)
    {
        // TODO : is this equal to other?
    }

    public int CompareTo(Int256 other)
    {
        // TODO : how does this compare to other?
    }

    public int CompareTo(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is null) return 1;
        if (obj is not Int256 int256) throw new ArgumentException("Obj must be of type Int256.");
        return CompareTo(int256);
    }
}
```

But I would still be able to use the operators with it; for example:

```cs
Int256 a = 123;
Int256 b = 456;

a == b; // False
a != b; // True
a > b;  // False
a >= b; // False
a < b;  // True
a <= b; // True
```

There is a problem, however.

Whilst those interfaces `IAutoEquatable<T>` and `IAutoComparable<T>` contain implementations for the operators, I'm still expected to implement them in `Int256`.

**Questions**

1. Why do `virtual` default implementations in interfaces still require implementation? i.e. why doesn't `Int256` just use the default implementation?
2. Might it be possible for a future version of C# to address this issue, such that we can use it to alleviate the need to write boilerplate code?

Raised here with the C# language design team: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/7032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer seems to be "yes and no". I can't explain exactly why, but it seems that there is no way to meaningfully do that.

You can "auto" implement the `IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool>` in the interface the following way:

```cs
public interface IAutoEquatable<T> : IEquatable<T>, IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool> where T : IAutoEquatable<T>
{
    static bool IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool>.operator ==(T? left, T? right)
    {
        Console.Write("ieop.== ");
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) && ReferenceEquals(right, null))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) || ReferenceEquals(right, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    static bool IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool>.operator !=(T? left, T? right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}

class Foo : IAutoEquatable<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo? other)
    {
        Console.Write("eq ");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it will not be called for `Foo == Foo`:

```cs
Do<Foo>(); // prints "ieop.== eq True"
Do1<Foo>(); // prints "ieop.== eq True"
Console.WriteLine(new Foo() == new Foo()); // prints "False"

void Do<T>() where T : IAutoEquatable<T>, new()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new T() == new T());
}

void Do1<T>() where T : IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool>, new()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new T() == new T());
}
```

And if the last one can be (somewhat) explained by the fact that a class does not inherit members from its interfaces ([as explained for example in the default interface members proposal spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#concrete-methods-in-interfaces)), but for the following I have even less explanations:

```cs
IAutoEquatable<Foo> foo1 = new Foo(); // or IEqualityOperators<Foo, Foo, bool> for both
IAutoEquatable<Foo> foo2 = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine(foo1 == foo2); // prints "False"
```

So personally I would suggest to go with `partial` classes and [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).

- [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) to play with.
- [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83007)

Comment: Thanks for that incredibly detailed answer. I've raised this with the C# language design team as well. Link in the question if you're interested.

Comment: The operators are static and can therefore not be inherited.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes, makes sense. Though in this case this would be a nice feature.

Comment: The feature could probably be implemented using the proposed [roles and extension](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/extensions.md).

Comment: Operators are used by compiler only in generic context. When type is not generic parameter, then compiler resolves to `Foo.op_Equality` if it's found, otherwise resolves to `Object.ReferenceEquals`. It's a very counterintuitive behavior